# I can't find podfile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I use terminal create podfile:

```
$ cd /Users/user_name/Desktop/CocoaPodsTest
$ touch Podfile
```

but i can't find podfile in finder ,but i can use 'vim podfile' to edit it.
and when i install podfile , it shows this information:

> [!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in
>   your Podfile like so:
>
> ```
> project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
> ```

when i restart my mac , if i install pod,it show this pod has not exists!

it happens from i update xcode version to 8.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use command **pod init** to [create a podfile](https://cocoapods.org/).

```
$ pod init
```

> Tip: CocoaPods provides a pod init command to create a Podfile with
>   smart defaults. You should use it.